# Is OAuth 2.0 access token sufficient to complete PayPal payment

Tags: api, paypal

I am trying to explore on the OAuth2.0 api provided by paypal. After gaining the OAuth access token, I am trying to find if that can be used for payment authentication.

Can anyone suggest some thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use it in conjunction with the [Permissions API](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Permissions.pdf) to allow users to grant permission for your application to make API calls on their behalf.